# Single Web Page low speed will affect on the all website speed and rank?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

One of the my website page speed is very low. but this is not my ranking url or i don't want to rank this url in SERP. but this page low speed will affect on my another page speed as well as all website page speed.

Comment: Loading speed in the Internet is quite a thing, since it can be slowed for multiple reasons; from your latency, all the way down the server's ISP, and even how thermal paste is applied on the bare-metal's CPU. Which speed tests have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean this page slows your whole website **Or** are you afraid this slow page will affect your whole website Ranking even if other pages aren't so slow?